# Tkinter/Python - comboBox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I created a comboBox inside my application, but I didn't want to be able to type inside it, just choose one of the options. Can you help me? 
Following is the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



def new_window_cad_emp():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.geometry("800x600+275+75")
    newWindow.resizable(height=False, width=False)

    mylabel = LabelFrame(newWindow, text="")
    mylabel.place(x=10, y=60, width=675, height=150)

    l_codcad = Label(newWindow, text="  Código")
    l_codcad.place(x=15, y=25)
    e_codcad = Entry(newWindow)
    e_codcad.place(x=75, y=25, width=40)

#<COMBOBOX>
    l_tipcad = Label(newWindow, text="Tipo")
    l_tipcad.place(x=500, y=100)

    tipoPessoa = ttk.Combobox(newWindow,
                                values=[
                                    "Pessoa Fisica",
                                    "Pessoa Juridica"])
    print(dict(tipoPessoa))
    tipoPessoa.place(x=540, y=100, width=115)
    tipoPessoa.current()

    print(tipoPessoa.current(), tipoPessoa.get())

#</COMBOBOX>


    bt = Button(newWindow, text="Novo")
    bt.place(x=700, y=15, width=90, height=30)
```

Comment: There is a `"readonly"` state flag in `Combobox` but i didn't see you have touched it. Show the output of: `print(tipoPessoa['state'])` or `print(tipoPessoa.cget('state'))`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

tipoPessoa = ttk.Combobox(newWindow,values=["Pessoa Fisica","Pessoa Juridica"],state="readonly")